# Eloquent 5.4, hasOneThrough method?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I know that `hasOneThrough` has been introduced to the latest Laravel build, however I can't really upgrade right now. What is the best way to do this?

I have got a `users` table, which I can't change the structure off, but I need to assign a `role` to these users, so I have created a pivot table, I want to add a method to my `User` model to get the role, and the user can only have **ONE**.

Tables:

`users` `user_roles` `user_assigned_roles`

I could use `hasManyThrough`, but this would expect many and I want to return a single model rather than a collection .

Comment: Do you want to use the relationship with eager loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could manage this with a combination of [one-to-one](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) & [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationships, and then access the role through an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators):

```
`users` 1 --- 1 `user_assigned_roles` m ---- 1 `user_roles`
```

So, in a `UserAssignedRole` model:

```
/** UserAssignedRole.php */

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserRole');
}
```

Then in your `User` model:

```
/** User.php */

public function assigned_role()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserAssignedRole');
}

// defining an accessor for your role:
public function getRoleAttribute()
{
    return $this->assigned_role->role;  // <--- Access the role of 'UserAssignedRole'
}
```

So in your controller (or wherever you want) you could do:

```
/** UsersController.php */

public function myFunction()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $role = $user->role; // <--

    dd($role->name);

    //
}
```

---

PS1: I strongly suggest you [to upgrade to the latest version of Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/upgrade) to make use of the new features and also for security reasons, fixes etc.

PS2: There is package called [Eloquent Has Many Deep](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep) by [Jonas Staudenmeir](https://github.com/staudenmeir) that manages this kind of relationship (and more) for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will look to upgrading once we get time.